# Getting an error when running import vpython, can someone help me out?

Tags: python, import, runtime-error, vpython

Installed vpython via cmd:  c:\Users>pip install vpython

Using Python 3.9.9

After installation I tested in cmd using python -m vpython.test and got the following error:

```
PS H:\Preston\folders\programming\py\vpython> python -u "h:\Preston\folders\programming\py\vpython\intro.py"

exit

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Preston\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 22, in Exit

    a = 1.0/zero

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: What's that `intro.py`?

Comment: just the file name.

Comment: I meant what it contains. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the import the code works fine, but if you read the error "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero" your code is dividing by zero try to change your code to something like  `if(zero==0): print("this is mathematically wrong")  else: a = 1.0/zero`

Comment: I think the division by zero is not in the asker's own code but in the library they installed.

Comment: ah i see, try to adding   this at the end of your code while True: rate(60) seems to works.

Comment: yes mkrieger1, my code consists entirely of import vpython.

Comment: NADJI, no effect.

Comment: Can't use import vpython but rather from vpython import * then use NADJI's recommendation of the while loop.
 
Full code:
from vpython import *
while True:
      rate(60)

Comment: Also make sure your interpreter is on, as mine got turned off at some point.  So it may be that you can use import vpython as NADJI suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From the installation instructions at vpython.org:

Using VPython with installed Python
We recommend installing the Anaconda Python distribution.

The vpython module currently works with Python versions 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10.

The 3D displays are rendered by WebGL in a browser window. For details, see
https://vpython.org/contents/VPythonArchitecture.pdf

The vpython module is available using
"conda install -c vpython vpython" or
"conda install -c conda-forge vpython" or
"conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 vpython" or
"pip install vpython"
To update to later versions of vpython use
"conda update -c vpython vpython" or
"pip install -U vpython"

When running from a terminal, if the program does not end with a loop
containing a rate() statement, you need to add "while True: rate(30)"
to the end of the program. This is not necessary when launching from
environments such as Jupyter notebook, IDLE, or Spyder.

Comment: Note too that at webvpython.org there is extensive documentation and a bunch of sample programs. Also, https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users is a forum of users of the vpython module.